# Terminal not opening and unable to run apt-get commands in Ubuntu 16.04. Python related error

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, python

I accidentally deleted python3 from ubuntu and now my terminal is not opening. I tried to update using `sudo apt-get update` and this the error I am getting. I tried all related solutions from the web and nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me with it? FYI I still got python 2.7.12 installed

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3-dateutil (2.4.2-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dateutil.postinst: 6: 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dateutil.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-dateutil (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 127
Setting up python3-roman (2.0.0-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-roman.postinst: 6: 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-roman.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-roman (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-docutils:
python3-docutils depends on python3-roman; however:
Package python3-roman is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-docutils (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python3-jmespath (0.9.0-2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a 
followup error from a previous failure.

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-jmespath.postinst: 6: 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-jmespath.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-jmespath (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: 
dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-botocore:
python3-botocore depends on python3-dateutil; however:
Package python3-dateutil is not configured yet.
python3-botocore depends on python3-docutils; however:
Package python3-docutils is not configured yet.
python3-botocore depends on python3-jmespath; however:
Package python3-jmespath is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-botocore (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Setting up 
python3-colorama (0.3.7-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-colorama.postinst: 6: 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-colorama.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-colorama (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Setting up 
python3-pygments (2.1+dfsg-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pygments.postinst: 6: 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pygments.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-pygments (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Setting up 
python3-rsa (3.2.3-1.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-rsa.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-rsa.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-rsa (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-s3transfer:
python3-s3transfer depends on python3-botocore; however:
Package python3-botocore is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-s3transfer (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
python3-dateutil
python3-roman
python3-docutils
python3-jmespath
python3-botocore
python3-colorama
python3-pygments
python3-rsa
python3-s3transfer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
dev (lifecycle-management) lambdas $ sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of python3 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-dateutil (2.4.2-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dateutil.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-dateutil.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-dateutil (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up python3-roman (2.0.0-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-roman.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-roman.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-roman (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-docutils:
python3-docutils depends on python3-roman; however:
Package python3-roman is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-docutils (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python3-jmespath (0.9.0-2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                      /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-jmespath.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-jmespath.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-jmespath (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-botocore:
python3-botocore depends on python3-dateutil; however:
Package python3-dateutil is not configured yet.
python3-botocore depends on python3-docutils; however:
Package python3-docutils is not configured yet.
python3-botocore depends on python3-jmespath; however:
Package python3-jmespath is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-botocore (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Setting up python3-colorama (0.3.7-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-colorama.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-colorama.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-colorama (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Setting up python3-pygments (2.1+dfsg-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pygments.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pygments.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-pygments (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Setting up python3-rsa (3.2.3-1.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-rsa.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-rsa.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-rsa (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-s3transfer:
python3-s3transfer depends on python3-botocore; however:
Package python3-botocore is not configured yet.
```

Comment: How did you run `sudo apt-get update` without a terminal?

Comment: Good thing you keep a good backup.  It will always save you from impulsive acts like this.

Comment: @melebius I ran that command from my IDE terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 16.04 Completely broken python3 + dpkg + apt-get!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092919/ubuntu-16-04-completely-broken-python3-dpkg-apt-get)